# Grails/Groovy regular expression- how to use (?i) to make everything case insensitive?

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I use the following RegEx:

```
url (blank:false, matches: /^(https?:\/\/)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+([\-\.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,40}(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(\/\S*)?/)
```

I want to add (?i) to make everything case insensitive. How should I add this?

Comment: Just place it at the beginning of the regex. `/(?i).../`

Comment: @stribizhev- no. The regex in groovy is (?i), and I get error if I try to put it in the end

Comment: @stribizhev: That syntax doesn't work in Groovy. `/.../` is actually [slashy string](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_slashy_string), not regex delimiters.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I have just read these are GStrings. Actually, there seems to be nothing about the flags.modifiers in the documentation, nor at regular-exprsssions.info. Sarit, Surely I would first try `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern, but the `/.../` syntax is so similar to regex delimiters I could not resist recommending to check that, too.

Comment: @stribizhev: I did try and find out about it before I posted that comment. The OP also reports error anyway...

Comment: [Here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-regular.html) is an example of a Groovy regex with `(?i)` in the pattern (`def lang = ~/^(?i)gr.*/`).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I can confirm the `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex makes it case insensitive.

Anyway, if your purpose is to reduce the regex length you can use the groovy [dollar slashy string](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_dollar_slashy_string) form. It allows you to not escape slashes `/` (the escape char becomes `$`).

In addition:

- the POSIX chars `\p{Alnum}` is the compact equivalent of `[0-9a-zA-Z]` (this way you can avoid to use the `(?i)` at all).
- remove unneeded backslashed dash from char class `[\-\.]` -> `[-.]` (it's not mandatory when the dash is the first or the last element and also the dot is always literal inside a character group).
- remove unneeded round brackets from the protocol section

In the following version I take advantage of the multiline support of dollar slashy string and the free-spacing regex flag `(?x)`:

```
$/(?x)
  ^                      # start of the string
  https?://              # http:// or https://, no need of round brackets
  (                      # start group 1, have to be a non capturing (?: ... ) but is less readable
    \p{Alnum}+           # one or more alphanumeric char instead of [a-zA-Z0-9]
    ([.-]\p{Alnum}+)*    # zero or more of (literal dot or dash followed by one or more [a-zA-Z0-9])
    \.                   # a literal dot
  )+                     # repeat the group 1 one or more
  \p{Alpha}{2,40}        # between 2 and 40 alphabetic chars [a-zA-Z]
  (:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?    # [optional] a literal colon ':' followed by at least one non zero digit till 5 digits
  (/\S*)?                # [optional] a literal slash '/' followed by zero or more non-space chars
/$
```

A dollar-slashy compact version:

```
$/^https?://(\p{Alnum}+([.-]\p{Alnum}+)*\.)+\p{Alpha}{2,40}([1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(/\S*)?/$
```

If you must use the slashy version this is an equivalent:

```
/^https?:\/\/(?:\p{Alnum}+([.-]\p{Alnum}+)*\.)+\p{Alpha}{2,40}(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(\/\S*)?/
```

A snippet of code to test all these regex:

```
def multiline_pattern = $/(?x)
  ^                      # start of the string
  https?://              # http:// or https://, no need of round bracket
  (                      # start group 1, have to be a non capturing (?: ... ) but is less readable
    \p{Alnum}+           # one or more alphanumeric char, instead of [a-zA-Z0-9]
    ([.-]\p{Alnum}+)*    # zero or more of (literal dot or dash followed by one or more [0-9a-zA-Z])
    \.                   # a literal dot
  )+                     # repeat the group 1 one or more
  \p{Alpha}{2,40}        # between 2 and 40 alphabetic chars [a-zA-Z]
  (:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?    # [optional] a literal colon ':' followed by at least one non zero digit till 5 digits
  (/\S*)?                # [optional] a literal slash '/' followed by zero or more non-space chars
/$

def compact_pattern = $/^https?://(\p{Alnum}+([.-]\p{Alnum}+)*\.)+\p{Alpha}{2,40}(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(/\S*)?/$

def slashy_pattern  = /^https?:\/\/(?:\p{Alnum}+([.-]\p{Alnum}+)*\.)+\p{Alpha}{2,40}(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(\/\S*)?/

def url1    = 'https://www.example-test.domain.com:12344/aloha/index.html'
def notUrl1 = 'htxps://www.example-test.domain.com:12344/aloha/index.html'
def notUrl2 = 'https://www.example-test.domain.com:02344/aloha/index.html'

assert url1 ==~ multiline_pattern
assert url1 ==~ compact_pattern
assert url1 ==~ slashy_pattern

assert !( notUrl1 ==~ compact_pattern )
assert !( notUrl1 ==~ slashy_pattern  )
assert !( notUrl1 ==~ slashy_pattern  )

assert !( notUrl2 ==~ compact_pattern )
assert !( notUrl2 ==~ slashy_pattern  )
assert !( notUrl2 ==~ slashy_pattern  )
```

Answer (score 6):

You place them in the regexp - like in java:

```
groovy:000> "http://example.COM" ==~ /^(https?:\/\/)(?:[a-z0-9]+([\-\.][a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,40}(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(\/\S*)?/
===> false
groovy:000> "http://example.COM" ==~ /^(?i)(https?:\/\/)(?:[a-z0-9]+([\-\.][a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,40}(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(\/\S*)?/
===> true
```