# Jenkinsfile stage when branch regex not working

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a declarative jenkinsfile setup and one of the stages I need to run when the branch has a certain naming convention. For some reason the stage is not running with the when block added as shown below:

```
when {
  branch pattern: '^([0-9]{5}-)?(?i)external-resources-.*',
  comparator: 'REGEXP'
}
```

So the example above I would like the stage to run when the branch matches anything that has the name `external-resources` in it. All other branches should be ignored.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test first your regexp in [`regex101.com`](https://regex101.com/r/KttHYx/8): adding a `(?i)` in the middle of it won't work.

As explained in "[Grails/Groovy regular expression- how to use (?i) to make everything case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34157891/6309)", you need to put it at the beginning.

```
(?i)^([0-9]{5}-)?external-resources-.*
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time with the help